# How to bundle recycler view item data and intent to another activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.adroit.leaveapplication.MainActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="400px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="continue"/>
```

My activity is as follows. I have used recycler view to create a form. I need to intent the information entered, into another activity.

I don't understand how to bundle the information for the following code and intent it.

I have set up a form and I take the user information in that form. I am beginner to android, so i am looking for some help here. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private FormBuilder mFormBuilder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupToolBar();

    setupForm();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupToolBar() {

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

}

private void setupForm() {

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mFormBuilder = new FormBuilder(this, mRecyclerView);

    FormHeader header1 = FormHeader.createInstance("Personal Info");
    FormElementTextEmail element11 = FormElementTextEmail.createInstance().setTitle("Email").setHint("Enter Email");
    FormElementTextPhone element12 = FormElementTextPhone.createInstance().setTitle("Phone").setValue("+91");
    FormElementTextPhone element13 = FormElementTextPhone.createInstance().setTitle("SAP ID").setHint("Enter SAP ID");

    FormHeader header2 = FormHeader.createInstance("Family Info");
    FormElementTextEmail element20 = FormElementTextEmail.createInstance().setTitle("Email(parent)").setHint("Enter Email");
    FormElementTextPhone element21 = FormElementTextPhone.createInstance().setTitle("Phone(parent)").setValue("+91");
    FormElementTextSingleLine element22 = FormElementTextSingleLine.createInstance().setTitle("Location").setHint("Enter Location");
    FormElementTextMultiLine element23 = FormElementTextMultiLine.createInstance().setTitle("Address");
    FormElementTextNumber element24 = FormElementTextNumber.createInstance().setTitle("Zip Code");

    FormHeader header3 = FormHeader.createInstance("Schedule");
    FormElementPickerDate element31 = FormElementPickerDate.createInstance().setTitle("From").setDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    FormElementPickerDate element32 = FormElementPickerDate.createInstance().setTitle("To").setDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    FormElementPickerTime element33 = FormElementPickerTime.createInstance().setTitle("Time").setTimeFormat("KK hh");


    List<BaseFormElement> formItems = new ArrayList<>();
    formItems.add(header1);
    formItems.add(element11);
    formItems.add(element12);
    formItems.add(element13);
    formItems.add(header2);
    formItems.add(element20);
    formItems.add(element21);
    formItems.add(element22);
    formItems.add(element23);
    formItems.add(element24);
    formItems.add(header3);
    formItems.add(element31);
    formItems.add(element32);
    formItems.add(element33);

    mFormBuilder.addFormElements(formItems);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> EXAMPLE CODE...

**IN RECYCLER VIEW ADAPTER CLASS**

public class ReciclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

...

```
@Override
public ReciclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   ...
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final LoadItem item = loadItems.get(position);

        holder.textvtitle.setText(item.title_story);
        holder.textvauthor.setText(item.author);
        holder.textvcreated.setText(item.created_at);

        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url_test = "https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/12/upshot/if-the-robots-...html
                //Passing string data in Intent...

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("access_web", url_test);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return loadItems.size();
}
```

> IN ACTIVITY TO PASSING DATA...

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    //String variable to save data...
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("access_web");

    WebView web = findViewById(R.id.webviewer);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web.loadUrl(url);
}
```

***I Hope to helping you!!***